# Uncaught ReferenceError: OrdersController is not defined on last line

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am getting Uncaught ReferenceError: **OrdersController is not defined on last line** while I have defined it. Have i missed something?

```
(function(){
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/',
    {
        controller:'CustomersController',
        templateUrl:'view/customers.html'

    })
    .when('/orders/:customersId',
    {
        controller:'OrdersController',
        templateUrl:'view/orders.html'

})
.otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});
});


myApp.controller('OrdersController',
    function ($scope,$routeParams){
        var customersId = $routeParams.customersId;
        $scope.orders = null;

        function init(){
            for(var i=0;i<$scope.customers.length;i++){
                if($scope.customers[i].id === parseInt(customersId)){
                    $scope.orders = $scope.customers[i].orders;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        $scope.customers = [
{id:1,name:'Deepak',age:21,spent:2.1,orders:[{id:1,sku:22,product:'Nike',total:100}]},
{id:3,name:'Vikram',age:32,spent:4.2,orders:[{id:3,sku:2,product:'Prada',total:200}]}
                           ];

    });

    OrdersController.$inject = ['$scope','routeParams'];
```

The customer controller and route associated are working very fine.

Comment: What's the purpose of the last line? $scope and $routeParams are already being injected when you are declaring the controller.

Comment: Do you have the full version of angular called in your index.html? **NOT** the min version? have you added ng-Route in your index.html?

Comment: I have called **angular.js** and **angular-route.js** in index.html. That is why another route and its controller are working fine.